# AttributeError: module 'emotions' has no attribute 'emotion'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, artificial-intelligence

Hi I'm currently making an AI I have things working but now out of nowhere I'm getting the error:
[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjx1W.png)

here is main.py

```
from greetings import greeting
from emotions import emotion

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('blue')

chosen_greeting = greeting.choose_greeting()

app = customtkinter.CTk() # Create screen
screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()
app.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
app.title("Login")


def check_emotion():
    found_emotion = emotion.check()
    if found_emotion == '0004302X':
        text = chat.cget("text")
        text = emotion.not_found()
        chat.configure(text=text)
    elif found_emotion == '00492X':
        the_emotion = emotion.goodBad()
        if the_emotion == 'bad':
            print("bad")
        elif the_emotion == 'good':
            print('good')
        elif the_emotion == 'meh':
            print('meh')
        else:
            print('error')

def HomeAI():
    global chat
    global text_given

    app.destroy()
    home = customtkinter.CTk()
    home.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
    home.title('AI screen')

    #AIChat = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(master=home, width=1000, height=900)
    #AIChat.place(rely=0.45, relx=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    chat = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=home, text="", font=('', 20))
    chat.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    chat.cget("text")
    chat.configure(text=chosen_greeting)

    text_given = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=home, width=500, placeholder_text="Enter message", font=('', 20))
    text_given.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.9, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    submit = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=home, width=30, text="Enter", font=('', 20), command=check_emotion)
    submit.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.9, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)




    home.mainloop()
```

This isn't the full code as I have a problem with people copying my code
and here is emotion.py (this is in a folder called emotions)

```
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
import random
import main


text = main.HomeAI().text_given

def not_found():
    notfound = "Well I have not seen this emotion before so I will try my hardest to understand"
    return notfound

def check():
    return msg

def goodBad():
    emotion = gb
    return emotion

def look():
    global msg
    count = 0
    global gb
    file = "emotions.xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    while True:
        count = count + 1
        if count == ws.max_row:
            msg = '0004302X'
            check()

        A = (ws[f'A{count}'].value)
        if A == text:
            msg = '00492X'
            gb = (ws[f'B{count}'].value)

        else:
            continue
```

I know I can put it into one file and this will make it better but my manager wants it to be all separate

It was working for a while then just stopped and I can't fix it :(

Comment: The indentation in your code is broken.

Comment: It is circular import issue.  Try to refactor your code, so that `main` need not be imported in `emotion.py`.